# VueJS: Custom Socket.io emits are not getting handled when triggered

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, vuejs2

I'm following the instructions on the [`vue-socket.io` npm download page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io). However, I can't get the `this.$socket.emit` method to work.

I have this in my `Main.vue` component:

```
sockets: {
    connect() {
        console.log('socket connected')
    },
    getAllOnline(token) {
        console.log(`Your token is ${token}`)
    }
},
created() {
    this.$socket.emit('getAllOnline', '123213')
}
```

I set up `VueSocketio` in my `main.js` file like this:

```
import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket.io';
Vue.use(VueSocketio, 'http://localhost:8080/');
```

I'm expecting to log whatever value was passed to the `getAllOnline()` function. But only the `connect()` callback in `sockets` object is being triggered.

Why isn't the callback for the `getAllOnline` emit being triggered?

---

#### Complete `main.js` file:

```js
// require some files
require('./assets/css/reset.css')
require('./assets/css/common.css')

// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket.io';

// Files import
import Main from './components/Main'
import Auth from './components/Auth'
import Register from './components/Register'

// Config of Vue
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = true

// Config of Axios
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

// Register to vue
Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
Vue.use(VueSocketio, 'http://localhost:8080/');

// API URL
const apiUrl = 'http://localhost/vue-dev/first-app/src/api/'

// Router
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: __dirname,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            props: {
                apiUrl: apiUrl
            },
            component: Main
        },
        {
            path: '/auth',
            props: {
                apiUrl: apiUrl
            },
            component: Auth
        },
        {
            path: '/register',
            props: {
                apiUrl: apiUrl
            },
            component: Register
        }
    ]
})

// Check if the route is exist on the routes
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(to.matched.length === 0) {
        return router.push('/auth')
    }
    return next()
})

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    template: '<router-view></router-view>'
})
```

Comment: Try moving the `sockets: { ...` property definition to the `new Vue` instance in `main.js`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used RxJS to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you didn't correctly configure the code on the server to handle this custom event.

The `this.$socket.emit('getAllOnline', '123213')` call in the `created` hook of your Vue component is emitting a signal to the server at `'http://localhost:8080/'`. If the server isn't listening for a `getAllOnline` event, nothing will happen.

The server code needs to listen for the event and *also* emit an event back to the client. It would look something like this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('getAllOnline', function(token){
    // code to handle the token goes here
    io.emit('getAllOnline', token);
  });
});
```

In the above example, the server emits the `getAllOnline` event back to the client with a `token` value. That value is what gets handled in the `sockets` callback for that event:

```
sockets: {
  getAllOnline(tokenFromServer) {
    console.log('getAllOnline', tokenFromServer);
  }
},
```

Comment: While this is working for me, I'm struggling to understand how it makes sense to place application logic in core index of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.$socket.emit('getAllOnline', '123213')`

https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io

Comment: @JohnReyM.Baylen have you tried to move this call to `mounted` hook or a method?